# Email client login for the virtual domains setup in postfix dovecot

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I have set up a mail server using Postfix and Dovecot. Right now I don't have sasl setup.
If I add a user using adduser command and login in to Thunderbird then there is no issue.

But now I have also set up virtual domains and I did not setup any password for the virtual domains. how can I log in to thunderbird using the virtual domain?

this is my virtual domain configuration in the postfix/main.cf

```
virtual_mailbox_domains = mydomain1.com, mydomain2.com, mydomain3.com
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/spool/mail
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtualmailbox
virtual_uid_maps = static:1002
virtual_gid_maps = static:1002
```

This is my postfix/virtualmailbox config

```
info@mydomain1.com mydomain1.com/info
info@mydomain2.com mydomain2.com/info
info@mydomain3.com mydomain3.com/info
```

Answer (score 0):

To log into virtual users through dovecot you need to enable some form of authentication for them (the system users are enabled by default).
Dovecot docs for virtual users: https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/virtual_users/

After adding the way you want to authenticate them to a file such auth-passwd in conf.d,
enable the corresponding file by uncommenting its include in the authentication config file and add the login info to your files/database